# RegEx, string contains at least 2 number between 1 and 9

Tags: regex

I have a 9 digit number where last 4 is optional (5+4). I want to say that there should be AT LEAST **TWO** [1-9] values (regardless of the position) in the first 5 character

Working Examples: `26505`, `00230`, `00021`, `23010`
Failing Examples: `20000`, `02000`

I built this, but not working the way that I want:

```
^(?=[1-9]{0,4}\d)\d{5}(-?\d{4})?$
```

Comment: I've reformatted the question, could you confirm that is correct?

Comment: @SaucedApples, please be careful when editing questions. You changed the context of that regex with your edit.

Comment: All versions work for me, https://regex101.com/r/J97oBC/1. Can you show your usage?

Comment: What regex flavor is it for?

Comment: Its written in Groovy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the majority of regex engines, there is no generic, easily expandable regex solution. In this case, you can spell out all possible combinations like in

```
^(?!0{5}|0{4}[1-9]|0{3}[1-9]0|0{2}[1-9]0{2}|0[1-9]0{3}|[1-9]0{4})\d{5}(?:-?\d{4})?$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y6vJwh/1) where the negative lookaheads fails the match if the first 5 digits only  contain 1 `1-9` digit and others are zeros.

However, if you have more than 5 digits to check for, say 50, that will become unwieldly.

A generic regex solution is possible in case your regex supports an infinite-width lookbehind (.NET, Python PyPi regex module), you may use

```
^\d{5}(?<=^\d*(?:[1-9]\d*){2})(?:-?\d{4})?$
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5Cd%7B5%7D(%3F%3C%3D%5E%5Cd*(%3F%3A%5B1-9%5D%5Cd*)%7B2%7D)(%3F%3A-%3F%5Cd%7B4%7D)%3F%5Cr%3F%24&i=26505%0D%0A00230%0D%0A00021%0D%0A23010%0D%0A%0D%0Abut%20not%0D%0A20000%0D%0A02000%0D%0A&o=m)

The `(?<=^\d*(?:[1-9]\d*){2})` lookbehind will require 2 `1-9` digits anywhere between the start of string and the 5th digit.

Comment: Just tested with ICU constrained-width lookbehind and that is too complex for that engine.

Comment: @tomsam What language did you try at regexplanet? I tried it with .Net and it worked.

Comment: I added a non-expandable common regex engine solution with the lookahead, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think that my regex using a positive lookbehind is a bit easier and a lot more readable.

```
(\d{5})(?<=[1-9]{2})-(\d+)
```

Live example:  https://regex101.com/r/CnEw7Z/2

Explanation -- There will be a set of 5 numbers, this has to have 2 characters between 1 and 9 in the field that matches \d{5} followed by a hyphen and some other numbers (\d+)

Let me know if this makes sense / works for you, and feel free to adjust capture groups to your liking.

Comment: This approach will work in case of an infinite-width lookbehind.

Comment: so, I could not get it worked at http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: This only works when the last 2 digits of the first 5 digit group are between 1 and 9. For instance, according to the question 26505 should be a match but this regex doesn't match it.